# Can someone interpret what this is asking for

Tags: approximation, numerical-analysis

I have this programming problem, but I really cant figure out what it wants me to do. Heres what it is:

> The cube root of a number can be found based on the observation that, if $t$ is an approximation of the cube root of $a$, then $\tfrac13\left(\tfrac{a}{t^2} + 2t\right)$ is a better approximation.
>
> Create a method `double betterCubeRoot(double a, double t)` that will find the cube root of $a$ accurate enough so that the difference between $t^3$ and $a$ is less than 0.0001. Use recursion.
>
> Then write the method `double cubeRoot(double a)` that makes use of the method with 1 as the initial value of $t$. Write a program that will test values both positive and negative.

Can someone please explain what this means. I dont understand how I am supposed to find the cube root of 'a' using the given equation. Thanks.

Here is what i have done:

```
public static double betterCubeRoot (double a, double t)
{
    double tCubed = Math.pow (t, 3);
    double dif = Math.abs (tCubed - a);

    double eq = ((a / (t * t)) + 2 * t) / 3;

    if (dif < 0.001)
    {
        return eq;
    }
    else
    {            
        return betterCubeRoot (eq, t) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are mathaholic, you may find it interesting to search more on Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: David's answer covers what we do here — algorithms (among other things). If you need help with the coding part, ask on [so]. You seem to be on the right track; be sure to indicate what part of the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Guess anything at all for the cube root of $a$: call that value $t$. $t′=\tfrac13(a/t^2+2t)$ is closer to $\sqrt[3]{a}$ than $t$ is, so use $t′$ as your next guess. Keep going.

Comment: ok I edited my answer with the addition of my code. What have i done wrong?

Comment: That's getting off-topic (this isn't the place for coding questions). Did you test it? Did it work? If $\mathrm{oldguess}^3$ is close enough to $a$, you return $\mathrm{newguess}$, which isn't the obvious way of doing it.